# Change context root of Wildfly Management Console

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Is there a way of changing the default url / path / context root of wildfly's integrated management console? I am using Apache as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to change it.

management console is avalibale on separate management interface and as such also on different port than your applications are.